# Pre-filling custom fields on New Post

Tags: custom-field

I'd like to have a number of custom fields automatically added and pre-filled (with a static default value) when a user opens the 'Add New Post' page in the admin panel to create a new post. The point is to have the custom fields already set with a default value so the person adding the article can see them and modify the values if needed.

I've looked through the hooks but I can't find any suitable one. I'm also not sure how to go about pre-populating the custom fields section in the new post form. Any ideas?

Comment: The way to add custom field is explained [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/186035/22728). In **step 2** change the input field to `<input type="number" name="wpse_value" value="default value here">`, and you are done!

Comment: From what I understand, add_meta_box() creates completely new fields in the new post page, whereas I'd like to use the built-in [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to have a *custom field*, already added and visible, for new posts:

```
/**
 * Preset a custom field for new posts
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/200554/26350
 */
add_action( 'save_post_post', function( $post_ID, $post, $update )
{
    if( 
            is_a( $post, '\WP_Post' )
        &&  'auto-draft' === $post->post_status
        &&  post_type_supports( $post->post_type, 'custom-fields' ) 
        && '0000-00-00 00:00:00' === $post->post_date_gmt 
        && $post_ID > 0
        && ! $update
    )
        add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wpse_custom_field', '123' );

}, 10, 3 );
```

Here we use the `save_post_{post-type}` hook.

We will then see this on the *Add New Post* screen:

[image: preset custom field]

As mentioned in the comments by @Alpha_Hydrae and @MarkKaplun, 
we should be able to simplify this to:

```
/**
 * Preset a custom field for new posts
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/200554/26350
 */
add_action( 'save_post_post', function( $post_ID )
{
    if( 'auto-draft' === get_post_status( $post_ID )
        &&  post_type_supports( get_post_type( $post_ID ), 'custom-fields' ) 
    )
        add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'wpse_custom_field', '123' );
} );
```

Comment: This works, thank you! It does feel a bit hacky with the date and auto-draft check (I assume these are to ensure that we're adding the custom field if and only if it's just loaded a brand new post page), so I hope it's future proof.

Comment: I don't think you need any other check except for `auto_draft`. I have done something similar using the status transition hook from auto_draft

Comment: yes, we can most likely remove some of these checks and I just added them here to be sure ;-)  There exists handy functions like `wp_is_post_revision()`  and `wp_is_post_autosave()` but I don't think we can mix them to our needs here.

Comment: Ok so I tested the updated version, seems to work fine, no duplicates or other issues when saving or updating the post.