# after checked the checkbox in backend, dont show social link on frontend

Tags: customization, metabox

I want to do something like if I checked/unchecked a checkbox in admin then all social links in the page footer on fronted hide/show.

```
function add_custom_meta_box() 
{add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Add or remove social link from footer", "custom_meta_box_markup", "page", "advanced", "high", null); }
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");

/* Displaying Fields in a Custom Meta Box */
function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
{
wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

?>
    <div class="meta_chk">
        <?php
            $checkbox_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-checkbox", true);
            if($checkbox_value == "")
            {
                ?>
                    <input name="meta-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <?php
            }
            else if($checkbox_value == "true")
            {
                ?>  
                    <input name="meta-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" checked>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        <label for="meta-box-checkbox">Remove social link</label>
    </div>
<?php  
}
/* Storing Meta Data */

function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) ||     !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-     box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
    return $post_id;

if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
    return $post_id;

if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;

$slug = "post";
if($slug != $post->post_type)
    return $post_id;

$meta_box_checkbox_value = "";

if(isset($_POST["meta-box-checkbox"]))
{
    $meta_box_checkbox_value = $_POST["meta-box-checkbox"];
}   
update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-checkbox", $meta_box_checkbox_value);
}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add special meta box to custom post type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186026/add-special-meta-box-to-custom-post-type)

Comment: This should not be treated as metabox for custom post type. This should be settings option or custom admin page, because, as I understand, he want to enable/disable social buttons for whole site.

Comment: yes @ Krzysztof Grabania you are right. I need if I checked button in admin then on front-end hide footer social link.

Comment: @WP_boss first, decide how you want to do this. If you agree with KrzysztofGrabania then you have disagree with me. If you want to disable social sharing links for only a post or post-specific then you have to do it with post meta (as you are doing now). But if you want to do it for the whole site, you need [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam I am sure I want to hide social links from footer. But not from whole site. Now tell how to do ?

Comment: But only if you are on specific pages you need to hide that buttons or this should work globally, for whole site?

Comment: @Krzysztof Grabania social link is in footer. I want to hide them by checkbox or select-box that is in admin. And as you know social link is in footer and footer is in all page's.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be in post metabox, because it is site setting, not specific page. You can create submenu position for settings in your admin panel by `add_submenu_page` function, for example:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_my_settings_submenu_page');
function add_my_settings_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 'Page title', 'Menu title', 'manage_options', 'my_settings', 'my_settings_submenu_callback');
}
```

Then you need to create callback for last argument where will be all logic of your code. This should be something like this:

```
<?php function my_settings_submenu_callback() { 
    if (isset($_POST['disable_footer_social'])) {
        update_option('disabled_footer_social', $_POST['disable_footer_social']);
    }

    $option = (bool) get_option('disabled_footer_social', false);
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>My Settings</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <table class="form-table">
                <th>Disable footer social buttons</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="disable_footer_social" value="0">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="disable_footer_social" value="1" <?php echo $option ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>>
                        Disable
                    </label>
                </td>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button('Submit'); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    </table>
<?php }
```

In your footer you can check if this option is checked by `get_option('disabled_footer_social')`, for example:

```
if (get_option('disabled_footer_social', false) != 1) {
    // show your buttons
}
```

- [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)
- [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

Comment: Mate I want this type...but according this URL I created Custom Meta Box but in last I cant create the action on "Publish" button on a page in wp-admin. URL : https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/